# Using variable inside a function

Tags: php

This seems like a really simple issue, but I'm not having any luck solving it and not entirely sure what to search. I am trying to get $logo to be used by the funciton, so that the image uses the variable defined on line 1:

```
$logo = 'http://dev.batman.com/logo.png';

function signup_email_body( $logo ){
  $body = '<img src="'.$logo.'" />';
}
```

The funciton is then triggered on signup and the src attribute is missing.

(n.b. the above is simplified code to save masses of HTML)

Comment: Well you need to pass the variable when you call the function. How do you call the function?

Comment: Pass it when you call the function. `signup_email_body($logo);`

Comment: Sorry guys, that's exactly what I've not done. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe a bit superfluous to create a function for this?

Comment: Why did this get downvoted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of `$body` is never returned from your function so it essentially goes away once the function call is finished executing. You need to return that value from your function in order to actually use it:

```
$logo = 'http://dev.batman.com/logo.png';

function signup_email_body( $logo ){
  return '<img src="'.$logo.'" />';
}

$body = signup_email_body( $logo ); // <-- now $body has that string value
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) is a neat idea in these cases.

```
$logo = 'http://dev.batman.com/logo.png';

function signup_email_body($logo)
{
   return sprintf('<img src="%s" />', $logo);
}

echo signup_email_body($logo);
```